# Прошу помощи распарсить лог для GROK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, grok

Есть лог

```
[2024-01-10 06:35:11.4292] [DEBUG] [] [GRT.ARM.Infrastructure.Integration.Services.TRE.TREListener] TREListener connected to https://GRT-srv1.test.lan:5800/ 
[2024-01-10 06:36:38.9158] [INFO] [] [GRT.ARM.Services.Implementations.Traffic.LaneController] LaneId: 2, Вызван метод [PlateScannedAsync]: [Номер: FG522EFD5, отправлен оператором - False.]. 
[2024-01-10 06:36:38.9158] [DEBUG] [] [GRT.ARM.Services.Implementations.Traffic.LaneController] LaneId: 2, Вызван метод [PlateScannedAsync]: [Номер получен от LPS.]. 
[2024-01-10 06:36:39.0443] [DEBUG] [] [GRT.ARM.Infrastructure.Storages.LicensePlateStorage] Adding LPS event for FG5224FD5 to storage. 
[2024-01-10 06:36:39.0443] [DEBUG] [] [GRT.ARM.Infrastructure.Storages.LicensePlateStorage] Taking LPS event for FG5224FD5 from storage. 
[2024-01-10 06:36:39.0999] [DEBUG] [] [GRT.ARM.Services.Notifications.ArmEventNotification.ArmEventNotificationHandler] Sending Arm Event, type: LicensePlateRecognized, Kafka ID: b19626e7-f8bb-49a4-a190-0be172af3733 
[2024-01-10 06:36:39.1482] [DEBUG] [] [GRT.ARM.Infrastructure.SignalR.Wrappers.PassageHubWrapper] LaneId: 2, отправлен сигнал SignalR из метода [NotifyOnPlateScannedAsync] с параметрами: [Number: FG5224FD5, RecognitionLevel: Accurate]. 
[2024-01-10 06:36:41.7794] [DEBUG] [] [GRT.ARM.Services.Implementations.Traffic.LaneController] LaneId: 2, Вызван метод [CarArrivedToEntranceZoneAsync].
```

Просьба помочь распарсить данный лог для Grok.
В данный момент у меня получилось только так:

```
^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\]\s+(\[%{WORD:loglevel}\]\s+)%{NOTSPACE}\s+\[%{DATA:field3}\]?%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

Буду признателен, за любую помощь.

Comment: В попытках разобраться, составил;
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[%{DATA:levellog}\] \[%{DATA:aspnet-user-identity}\] \[%{DATA:field3}\]\s*%{DATA:field4} \[%{DATA:field5}\]\s*%{DATA:field6} \[%{DATA:field7}\]
Но это все равно не то что я хотел бы увидеть в конце, скорее всего под основные строчки нужно составить свои правила....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих проб и ошибок пришел к выводу, что на каждую строчку нужен свой фильтр, что и было сделано. Создано 12 фильтров на каждую строчку, все добавлено в filter.conf и я получил то что хотел. Так что вопрос закрыт.